# Search not functiong using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I have a project that I'm doing now and my project consist of CRUD functions and it works fine. My project also has its pagination and search function.

The pagination is working but the search function does not seem to work. What I want is, a search where I can search anything within my table like I want to search all the fields or maybe a live search. Can somebody please help me.

Dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'survey';

try{
$db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$dbname}",db_username,$db_password);
}
catch(PDOException $exception{
echo $exception->getMessage();
}
include_once 'class.paginate.php'
$paginate = new paginate($DB_con);
?>
```

Class.paging.php

```
<?php
class paginate{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
     $this->db = $DB_con;
     }

     public function dataview($query)
    {
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
     $stmt->execute();

     if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
     {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
               ?>
               <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['province']; ?></td>
               <!-- <td><a href="<? php echo $row['tuts_link']; ?>">visit</a></td> -->

               </tr>
               <?php
            }
     }
     else
     {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
     }

 }
 public function search($query)
 {
  $stmt=$this->db->prepare($query);
  $query = '%' . $query . '%';
  $stmt->bindparam('query', $query,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();



  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  if(empty($result) or $result == false)
return array();
 else
  return $result;
  }
 public function  paging($query,$records_per_page)
 {
    $starting_position=0;
    if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
    {
          $starting_position= ($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
    }
    $query2=$query." limit. $starting_position,$records_per_page";
    return $query2;
 }

 public function   paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
 {

    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($total_no_of_records > 0)
    {
        ?><tr><td colspan="4"  align="center"><?php
         $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
        $current_page=1;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
             $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
        }
        if($current_page!=1)
        {
           $previous =$current_page-1;
           echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
           echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
         for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
        {
        if($i==$current_page)
        {
            echo "<strong><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;text-decoration:none'>".$i."</a> </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a  href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
   }        if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
   {
    $next=$current_page+1;
    echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }
   ?></td></tr><?php
  }
 }
}
```

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

```
  <body>
   <div id="search-wrapper">
<form name="search" method="GET" action="">
    <table id="search" class="table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <input name="var1" type="text" id="search-box">&nbsp;
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE (`username` like :query or `password` like :query) ";
 $paginate->search($query)
?>
</form>

 </div>

 <div id="table-wrapper" class="table-responsive">
    <table id="data" class="table table-striped table-hover">

        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login";       
    $records_per_page=20;
    $newquery = $paginate->paging($query,$records_per_page);
    $paginate->dataview($newquery);
    $paginate->paginglink($query,$records_per_page);  
    ?>
    </table>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 <a  href="http://cleartuts.blogspot.com/">cleartuts.blogspot.com</a>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: there should not be any spaces in here `dbname=    {$dbname}`

Comment: @Fred ii i'sorry its just a typo.i edit my code

Comment: see if http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php returns anything.

Comment: @fred theres nothing wrong in my connection of database im just put all my code so it can ce more understanding..my only problem with my code is that the search function is not working

Comment: I see `action=""` and this says to execute within that file being index.php and I don't see how you're including any of your other files for the query stuff. Again, check for errors here and look at your console and do a var_dump. Btw `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>` should be in <head> - also why are you using LIKE?

Comment: @fred ive been doing these for about 3days now and i cant figure out on how to make it work..can you please help me..pleaasee.

Comment: I use like because if someone dont know what theyre searching then they can just put anything in the search box and it will show all the records with matching those inputted